# CreateView with ListView in django init form

Tags: django, listview, create-view

I'm working with [sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload) for multiple upload images, so I want to achieve that when the user enter a page. The photos uploaded by him appears in the page so, is there a way no initialize a django CreateView with all the objects displayed like a ListView?

I have this createview:

```
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
model = Picture
fields = "__all__"
template_name = 'fileupload/picture_form.html'
# form_class = PictureForm

# def get_initial(self):
#     initial = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_initial()
#     initial = initial.copy()
#     files = [serialize(p) for p in self.get_queryset()]
#     data = {'files': files}
#     response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
#     response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
#     return response


def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.usuario_id = self.request.user.id
    self.object.save()
    usuario = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)

    if usuario:
        photos = Picture.objects.filter(usuario_id=usuario.id)
        for photo in photos:
            photo.usuario_id = self.request.user.id
            photo.save()

    files = [serialize(self.object)]
    data = {'files': files}
    response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
    return response

def form_invalid(self, form):
    data = json.dumps(form.errors)
    return HttpResponse(content=data, status=400, content_type='application/json')
```

ListView

```
class PictureListView(ListView):
model = Picture
template_name = 'fileupload/picture_list.html'
```

Html

```
{% extends "fileupload/upload_base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <ul>
    {% for picture in object_list %}
        <img src="/media/{{ picture.file }}" />
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution was to use get_context_data method

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['pictures'] = Picture.objects.filter(usuario_id=self.request.user.id)
    return context
```

Template.html

```
{% extends "fileupload/upload_base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load upload_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% for picture in pictures %}
        <img src="/media/{{ picture.file }}" />
    {% endfor %}
{%endlock%}
```